# How to give css to tooltip in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

```
    protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
           {
               if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
               {
                   foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                   {
                       string cellText = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;

                       if (cell.Text.Length > 10)
                       {
                           cell.Text = cell.Text.Substring(0, 10) + "....";
                           cell.ToolTip = cellText;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
```

From the above method we have tooltip on every columns in the table.
Below code shows that 6th column will only populate  tooltip.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
           focus.($("#grdStudentList td:nth-child(6)"));
          }); 
     </script>
```

How i will give css  to this focus  which display as tooltip.

Comment: `grdStudentList..Attributes.Add("class", "some-class")`.this way you can make and give class

Comment: I think tooltip is nothing but a `title` attribute. you can use `var tooltip = $('selector').attr('title'); $('selector').attr('title',null);$('selector').prepend($('<span class="tooltip">'+tooltip+'</span>'))` and then you may apply styles to `.tooltip{}`

Comment: It doesn't work for me..:(

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all the  word contains more than 10 characters

```
( if (cell.Text.Length > 10)
```